# Laravel 5 Image Upload

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading

I am trying to upload Images with a form. I have 5 fields in total and don't want to make all fields required. However there is an exception if I leave one of the fields blank. But everything works fine when I upload all 5 images.

I have no rules in my $rules array. Something goes wrong with `isValid()`.
Error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProfilesController.php line 191:
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on a non-object.
```

Can somebody point me into the right direction please.

My Controller:

```
    public function update(ProfileRequest $request, $id)
    {
      $profile = Profile::findOrFail($id);

      $request->merge([ 'wifi' => $request->has('wifi') ? true : false,
                          'takeaway'=> $request->has('takeaway') ? true : false,
                          'ec'=> $request->has('ec') ? true : false,
                          'creditcard'=> $request->has('creditcard') ? true : false,
                          'cash'=> $request->has('cash') ? true : false,
                          'wheelchair'=> $request->has('wheelchair') ? true : false,
                          'outdoor'=> $request->has('outdoor') ? true : false,
                          'tv'=> $request->has('tv') ? true : false,
                          'service'=> $request->has('service') ? true : false,
                          'smoking'=> $request->has('smoking') ? true : false,
                          'reservation'=> $request->has('reservation') ? true : false,
                          'brunch'=> $request->has('brunch') ? true : false,
                        ]);





      // getting all of the post data
      $file = array('image_profilehero' => Input::file('image_profilehero'),
                    'image_avatar' => Input::file('image_avatar'),
                    'pdf' => Input::file('pdf'),
                    'restaurantscene1' => Input::file('restaurantscene1'),
                    'restaurantscene2' => Input::file('restaurantscene2')
              );

      // setting up rules
      $rules = array(//'image_profilehero' => 'required',
                     //'image_avatar' => 'required'

              ); //mimes:jpeg,bmp,png and for max size max:10000

      // doing the validation, passing post data, rules and the messages
      $validator = Validator::make($file, $rules);
      if ($validator->fails()) {
        // send back to the page with the input data and errors
        return Redirect::to('backend/profile')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
      }
      else {
        // checking file is valid.
        if (Input::file('image_profilehero') or Input::file('image_avatar')->isValid() or Input::file('pdf')->isValid() or Input::file('restaurantscene1')->isValid() or Input::file('restaurantscene2')->isValid()) {
          $destinationPathAvatar = 'uploads/avatar'; // upload path Avatar
          $destinationPathProfileHero = 'uploads/profilehero'; // upload path ProfileHero
          $destinationPathPdf = 'uploads/speisekarten'; // upload path ProfileHero

          //Restaurant Scene Bilder
          $destinationPathRestaurantScene1 = 'uploads/restaurantscene'; // upload path RestaurantScene
          $destinationPathRestaurantScene2 = 'uploads/restaurantscene'; // upload path RestaurantScene

          $extensionAvatar = Input::file('image_avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
          $extensionProfileHero = Input::file('image_profilehero')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
          $extensionPdf = Input::file('pdf')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension

          $extensionRestaurantScene1 = Input::file('restaurantscene1')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
          $extensionRestaurantScene2 = Input::file('restaurantscene2')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension

          //$fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image

          $fileNameAvatar = '/avatar/avatar_'.Auth::user()->id.'.'.$extensionAvatar;
          $fileNameProfieHero = '/profilehero/profilehero_'.Auth::user()->id.'.'.$extensionProfileHero;
          $fileNamePdf = '/speisekarten/pdf_'.Auth::user()->id.'.'.$extensionPdf;

          $fileNameRestaurantScene1 = '/restaurantscene/scene1_'.Auth::user()->id.'.'.$extensionRestaurantScene1;
          $fileNameRestaurantScene2 = '/restaurantscene/scene2_'.Auth::user()->id.'.'.$extensionRestaurantScene2;

          Input::file('image_profilehero')->move($destinationPathProfileHero, $fileNameProfieHero); // uploading file to given path
          Input::file('image_avatar')->move($destinationPathAvatar, $fileNameAvatar); // uploading file to given path
          Input::file('pdf')->move($destinationPathPdf, $fileNamePdf); // uploading file to given path

          Input::file('restaurantscene1')->move($destinationPathRestaurantScene1, $fileNameRestaurantScene1); // uploading file to given path
          Input::file('restaurantscene2')->move($destinationPathRestaurantScene2, $fileNameRestaurantScene2); // uploading file to given path

          // sending back with message
          return redirect('backend/profile')->with([
            'flash_message_important' => false,
            'flash_message' => 'All done'
          ]);
        }
        else {
          // sending back with error message.
          return redirect('backend/profile')->with([
            'flash_message_important' => false,
            'flash_message' => 'Upps. Something's wrong.'
          ]);
        }
      }
      //return redirect('backend/profile');
      $profile->update($request->all());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not accounting for an empty or missing file, it's just assuming there's a file there and attempting to `move` it. So you end up calling methods on a non-object, likely `null`. You just need to do a bit of extra work to ensure you actually have objects before you call methods on them, like this:

```
$pdf = Input::file('pdf');
if ($pdf) {
    $extension = $pdf->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $pdf->move($destinationPathPdf, $fileNamePdf);
}
```

This way, if there's no PDF file, the if statement will be false and will skip calling methods on it, so you avoid that kind of error. It's generally good practice to do this.